# How to remove the delay on showing the result?

Tags: flutter, dart

so here is the thing. after scanning 3 different barcodes. i have created a button that will show the value of those.
So it is like this.

```
barcode 1 - name1 - [Get info]
barcode 2 - name2 - [Get info]
barcode 3 - name3 - [Get info]
```

When i press get info of barcode 1, it will show the right result which is "name1" then when i press get info of barcode 2, it will show "name1" then if i press it again it will show "name2" which is now correct. its the same for barcode 3, so what happen is, after the first get info, i need to press it 2 times to get the right result. so how can i fix that? thank you!!

```
final List<dynamic> list = <dynamic>[];
  String barcode = "";
  String result = '';
  String a1;

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = barcode;
        list.insert(
          0,
          barcode,
        );
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          this.barcode = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        this.barcode = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }

  Future<List<dynamic>> getInfo(index) async {
    final response = await http
        .post('http://172.16.9.23/pndrMob/cafunct/scanner.php', body: {
      "barcode": list[index],
    });
    //print(response.body.toString());
    var result = json.decode(response.body);
    //print(result);

    setState(() {
      a1 = result[0]["SolarPanelName"];
    });
  }

  showrentry(BuildContext context) {
    Widget okButton = TextButton(
      child: Text("Ok"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Panel"),
      content: Text(a1),
      actions: [okButton],
    );
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Solar Panel Barcode Scan"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  height: 50.0,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text('${list[index]}'),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            getInfo(index);
                            print(a1);
                            showrentry(context);
                          },
                          child: Text("Get Info"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        onPressed: () {
          _scanQR();
        },
        label: Text("Scan"),
        icon: Icon(Icons.qr_code),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `await`ing your result. Mark the function as `async` and `await` `getInfo`:

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  await getInfo(index);
  print(a1);
  showrentry(context);
},
```